# how can i make this command loop? [Discord.js]

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have this command but I don't have an idea how to make it loop until I turn off the bot. I will be really grateful if you can help me. I have to mention that I need the message to keep changing.

the code I want to loop is this:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "spam",
  description: "face spam",
  execute(message, args) {
    let messages = [
      "Ghg&gjhgTF55$FGjhuc$%",
      "ggt6rjhf*r8rfhgo(gFT&",
      "F^v 6r796GIGYv6rcKUYg",
      "g7v%C75C&TOHbgv*C^ruk",
      "hgC^%4x7vV(P&v0b87&^C",
      "hguiv^&vr675rXC&5vvv6",
      "78v tv8976r9uyv ci y6",
      "b87%687*V8V*v7UYVOUYV",
      "bt8787V5V9&^v*&5Xdiov",
      " *^&t*^&V&cr(R5kjYGBk",
    ];
    const message = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
    message.channel.send(message);
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use setInterval

```js
const timeInMs = 1000;
let msg; // not const
setInterval(function(){
 // The code you want to repeat
 message.channel.send(msg);
 msg= messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * (messages.length))]
}, timeInMs);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

```js
let bot = null;
let messages = [
  "Ghg&gjhgTF55$FGjhuc$%",
  "ggt6rjhf*r8rfhgo(gFT&",
  "F^v 6r796GIGYv6rcKUYg",
  "g7v%C75C&TOHbgv*C^ruk",
  "hgC^%4x7vV(P&v0b87&^C",
  "hguiv^&vr675rXC&5vvv6",
  "78v tv8976r9uyv ci y6",
  "b87%687*V8V*v7UYVOUYV",
  "bt8787V5V9&^v*&5Xdiov",
  " *^&t*^&V&cr(R5kjYGBk",
];

function start() {
  bot = setInterval(function () {
    const msg = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
    console.log(msg);
  }, 1000);
}

function stop() {
  bot && clearInterval(bot);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="start()" >Start</button>
<button onclick="stop()" >Stop</button>
```